# Using mapping data flows within for-each activity of azure data-factory pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

**Scenario**: I have SQL DB CDC net changes coming into a csv file. In the pipeline for each row in the csv file need to check for updates, inserts and deletes and do some changes in my warehouse DB.

**Pipeline**:

[image: pipeline]

**mapping dataflow:**

[image: dataflow]

**Problem**:

How to use the item() from foreach in dataflow and fetch that record from csv file and process. I'm not seeing any field/option in source step of dataflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you could add a parameter in Data Flow:

[image]

Then out of the Data flow, click the Data Flow, set the data flow parameter with Pipeline expression:

[image]

Then you could set the Foreach `item()` as the dataflow parameter:

[image]

Now,you can use the item() from foreach in dataflow and fetch that record from csv file and process.

Hope this helps.

Comment: From the annals of "just because you CAN doesn't mean you SHOULD" :)

You are essentially using a Lookup activity to read each line from a CSV file and send it to the data flow one row at a time.

Please do NOT do this!!

Just use that CSV file in the data flow Source transformation. Let the data flow read each row and load into data frames in Spark.

You'll thank me later!

Comment: Thanks Leon. I'm already doing this as you mentioned. Do i need to any special thing within dataflow source step to inform to read from this parameter instead of dataset configured for the source ? the first source step of dataflow still pointing to the same dataset which is having full csv access

Comment: @VT0906 No, we can not use the Forach item() as the source dataset in Data Flow. The only thing we can do is building an expression with  the item() to filter the data in full csv, add the actives, such as  alter row or DerivedColumn.

Comment: Yes, you can use @item() as a dataset parameter in your data flow activity.

The recommendation is to use the Source transformation in your data flow to filter the CSV files for your source. Use the wildcard path in the Source options instead of ForEach.

ForEach with data flows is not a recommended pattern. I talk about this in our perf doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-performance#looping-through-file-lists

Answer (score 1):

No need to use ForEach here. The data flow can read each line from your CDC source file and you can apply the appropriate insert, update, merge, delete operation as policies in the Alter Row transformation.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I guess the suggestion is to use conditional split of rows and do the process. Could you give little more information on this ?

Comment: Just use the Alter Row transformation.

Set your source as the CSV file.

Set an expression for each Update, Insert, Upsert, and Delete condition.